# Tasks on Closed Android Apps: Handling Push Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently working on a project using Capacitor/Cordova for an Android app. I have encountered a challenge related to handling push notifications when the app is completely closed.

Specifically, I am looking for guidance on running tasks in response to receiving push notifications, especially when the app is closed. I want to extract data from the push notification and perform certain actions, such as storing the data.

I have explored the documentation for Capacitor/Cordova and have implemented basic push notification handling, but I am unsure about the best practices or methods for handling these notifications in the background when the app is closed.

If anyone in the community has experience with this or can provide insights, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Feel free to share any code snippets, relevant documentation, or tips that might help me overcome this challenge.

Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Best regards,